# Inclusive RavenDB date range query not including matching date values as expected

Tags: ravendb, lucene.net, ravendb-studio

I am trying to understand date range filters in RavenDB. When I attempt to query for records within a particular date range as follows:

```
Date:[2015-08-18T06:00:00.000Z TO 2015-08-19T06:00:00.000Z]
```

The document type being queried contains the following record (which I am expecting to be returned by the above query).

```
{
    "yada_yada": "stuff",
    "Date": "2015-08-18T06:00:00Z",
    "Source": "Joe Bob",
    "Comments": "The force is strong with this one.",
    "Id": "agentactivities-1"
}
```

The query returns no results. I've tried to modify the query such as `Date:[2015-08-18T06:00:00Z TO 2015-08-19T06:00:00.000Z]` (removing the decimal value) with the same result. However, if I remove the `Z` (Date:[2015-08-18T06:00:00.000 TO 2015-08-19T06:00:00.000Z]), the record is returned by the query. Also, modifying the starting range arg an hour earlier seems to work as well (`Date:[2015-08-18T05:00:00.000Z TO 2015-08-19T06:00:00.000Z]`)

What am I missing here? As I understand it, using the `[]` symbols should result in an inclusive range so why doesn't the query return this record???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your date in the document is not a valid date time value. It need to be with ISO 8601 format date.

This is the format:

"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffzzz"

Comment: Thanks for the response. You're right, modifying the date format on _both_ the document and the query to carry 7 decimal point values did "fix" the issue with the results. However, it seems like there's a deeper issue regarding the comparison of dates values which, I assume, is a Lucene.NET implementation detail. Based on your knowledge of Lucene(.NET), do you know if it's feasible to consider a PR to improve the comparison of date values so that `2015-08-18T05:00:00.000Z == 2015-08-18T05:00:00.0000000Z`?

Comment: If you send a PR, we'll certainly consider it

Comment: I'll gladly look into it. Am I correct in my assumption that this is a Lucene.Net implementation detail or should I be looking at RavenDB? I am unfamiliar with the internals of both libraries so any tips you can provide to help me arrive would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at RavenDB, yes.

Comment: In particular, https://github.com/ayende/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Database/Indexing/AnonymousObjectToLuceneDocumentConverter.cs